# How to apply Gaussian quadrature formula

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral

> Evaluate $$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\ dx $$ employing three points Gaussian quadrature formula, finding the required weights and residues. Use five decimal places for computation.

How to change integral limits to -1 to 1?

Comment: Needing to change the limits usually suggests you need to think of a suitable substitution. What have you tried?

Comment: Try $x=\dfrac{t+1}{t-1}$ the integrand becomes $-\frac{2 e^{-\frac{t+1}{t-1}}}{(t-1)^2}$

Comment: See $\mathbf{25.4.45}$ in [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_890.htm).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_890.htm)
>   $\ds{\mathbf{25.4.45}}$ *Formula* which is *Gauss-Laguerre Quadrature Formula*:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x}\dd x & \approx w_{1} + w_{2} + w_{3} = 1.0000003\,,\qquad\qquad\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{w_{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0.0103893}
\\
\ds{w_{2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0.711093}
\\
\ds{w_{3}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0.278518}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> The *Relative Error* becomes
>   $\ds{\verts{1.0000003 - 1 \over 1}\ 100\ \% =
> \bbx{3 \times 10^{-5}\ \%}}$ !!!.